# Nested JSON in Elastic Search Not Being Picked Up

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following JSON Structure:

```
{
    "Dataset": "kh_offers",
    "Instance": "20140817",
    "Record": [{
        "45": "{\"errorCode\":null,\"runStatusId\":null,\"lakeHdfsPath\":\"/user/jmblnvr/20140817_011500_zoot_kohls_offer_init.dat\",\"fieldIndex\":45,\"datasetFieldName\":\"PRESENTABLE_FLAG\",\"datasetFieldSum\":0.0,\"datasetFieldMin\":0.0,\"datasetFieldMax\":0.0,\"datasetFieldMean\":0.0,\"datasetFieldSigma\":0.0,\"datasetFieldNullCount\":0.0,\"datasetFieldObsCount\":0.0,\"datasetFieldKurtosis\":0.0,\"datasetFieldSkewness\":0.0,\"frequencyDistribution\":\"(T,170544)\",\"id\":null,\"fieldType\":\"STRING\"}"
    }, {
        "30": "{\"errorCode\":null,\"runStatusId\":null,\"lakeHdfsPath\":\"/user/jmblnvr/20140817_011500_zoot_kohls_offer_init.dat\",\"fieldIndex\":30,\"datasetFieldName\":\"FIRST_PYMT_DATE\",\"datasetFieldSum\":0.0,\"datasetFieldMin\":0.0,\"datasetFieldMax\":0.0,\"datasetFieldMean\":0.0,\"datasetFieldSigma\":0.0,\"datasetFieldNullCount\":0.0,\"datasetFieldObsCount\":0.0,\"datasetFieldKurtosis\":0.0,\"datasetFieldSkewness\":0.0,\"frequencyDistribution\":null,\"id\":null,\"fieldType\":\"STRING\"}"
    }]
}
```

I am wondering why Elastic Search cannot handle this nested structure? Is it because of the weird \ that makes it valid JSON when my writer is writing it? Is it some other reason?

Elastic Search is picking up the first 3 fields but when I drill down into records it is just thinking its one mass block of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing it in as a string, because you have surrounded it with quotation marks and are escaping the 'inner' quotation marks. Just pass in the JSON:

```
{
    "Dataset": "kh_offers",
    "Instance": "20140817",
    "Record": [{
        "45": {
            "errorCode": null,
            "runStatusId": null,
            "lakeHdfsPath": "/user/jmblnvr/20140817_011500_zoot_kohls_offer_init.dat",
            "fieldIndex": 45,
            "datasetFieldName": "PRESENTABLE_FLAG",
            "datasetFieldSum": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldMin": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldMax": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldMean": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldSigma": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldNullCount": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldObsCount": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldKurtosis": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldSkewness": 0.0,
            "frequencyDistribution": "(T,170544)",
            "id": null,
            "fieldType": "STRING"
        }
    }, {
        "30": {
            "errorCode": null,
            "runStatusId": null,
            "lakeHdfsPath": "/user/jmblnvr/20140817_011500_zoot_kohls_offer_init.dat",
            "fieldIndex": 30,
            "datasetFieldName": "FIRST_PYMT_DATE",
            "datasetFieldSum": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldMin": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldMax": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldMean": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldSigma": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldNullCount": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldObsCount": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldKurtosis": 0.0,
            "datasetFieldSkewness": 0.0,
            "frequencyDistribution": null,
            "id": null,
            "fieldType": "STRING"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: What did you use to clean up the JSON so easily ? If I just remove all of the / it says its improper JSON?

Comment: Honestly I just opened it up in an intellij scratch file and read through it. I replaced all the `\"` with `"` then cleaned it up by  hand.. I don't know, I spend a lot of time with JSON I guess :-)

Comment: Thanks hah, when I did a simple replace all \ it freaked out so, I will look into it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Your Record Describe as string not document. remove quote and \ and send it again.

```
{
    "Dataset": "kh_offers",
    "Instance": "20140817",
    "Record": [{

        "30": {"errorCode":null,"runStatusId":null,"lakeHdfsPath":"/user/jmblnvr/20140817_011500_zoot_kohls_offer_init.dat","fieldIndex":30,"datasetFieldName":"FIRST_PYMT_DATE","datasetFieldSum":0.0,"datasetFieldMin":0.0,"datasetFieldMax":0.0,"datasetFieldMean":0.0,"datasetFieldSigma":0.0,"datasetFieldNullCount":0.0,"datasetFieldObsCount":0.0,"datasetFieldKurtosis":0.0,"datasetFieldSkewness":0.0,"frequencyDistribution":null,"id":null,"fieldType":"STRING"}
    }]
}
```

like this